# SQLite Query: Huge Slowdown From Browser to Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an app that takes raw transit data and displays the upcoming train schedule. I use the following query to retrieve the list of stations (from a table containing approximately 50,000 entries for stop times):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(stops._id, 0, LENGTH(stops._id)) as _id, stops.stop_name 
FROM trips, stop_times, stops                                  
WHERE trips._id = 'B'
AND trips.trip_id = stop_times._id 
AND stop_times.stop_id = stops._id
```

I ran this query in an SQLite browser and it executed in about 0.8 seconds. But when I execute it in my DatabaseHelper class using rawQuery(), it takes in excess of 5 minutes on my physical device. I added some logging statements to see where the slowdown was occurring and it appears that it is the query itself which is taking a long time, not the inflation of the View. When I execute the same query without the DISTINCT option, it executes in about 1 second.

I could understand the Android library taking a bit longer to execute than the browser but it should not be several hundred times slower. Is there something about the DISTINCT option that is causing this?

Comment: Actually I would expect that your Android device would be several hundred times slower than a good desktop or laptop computer!

Comment: Yeah but without the DISTINCT option, it executes in 1 second on the device. I realize that adds more work to the query but it still seems like too much of a slowdown. I was curious if DISTINCT commonly has such a drastic effect. If that's the price to pay for it, I'll need to find another way to get the data.

Comment: I wonder if the substr function is slow.  Can you get away with just `select distinct stops._id as _id, ...`? At least testing it that way could help point out the problem.

Comment: Removing the SUBSTR didn't help. I think it must just be the overhead from having to filter out duplicate rows and adding the results to a Cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` takes time to process as it is a matter of sorting and selection. In case if you have huge data, DISTINCT will just make it even worse. I would suggest you to breakdown your query into smaller parts and/or do the filtering pragmatically

Comment: I think I will just figure out a different way. Does this have something to do with adding the returned data to a Cursor object? Again, this took less than a second in an SQLite browser.

Comment: no, Cursor shouldn't be a problem. What you may do is to fetch the records without DISTINCT (as it takes just a second), and then perform this distinction via your code. I hope it should cut a lot time compare to the old technique

Comment: In the end, I just had to split the stop_times table up by the train route and add some application code to determine which table to look in. This dramatically reduced the time needed to execute the query. I found that anything that takes more than 0.1 seconds on my computer took too long on the device.